# white filter JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, filtering

I'm getting an API response from my backend and want to forward it to the client (browser) through JS.
But there shouldn't be the hole response from the server.

One JSON could look like:

```
"{\"total\":6,\"sort\":{\"field\":\"created_at\",\"order\":\"desc\"},\"constraints\":       [],\"pagination\":  {\"current\":1,\"previous\":null,\"next\":null,\"per_page\":25,\"pages\":1,\"count\":6},\"response\":[{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Prof. Dr. Dr. h. c.\",\"people_count\":2,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"Dr. h. c.\",\"people_count\":1,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Dr. Dr.\",\"people_count\":0,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":true}},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Prof. Dr.\",\"people_count\":0,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":true}},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"Prof.\",\"people_count\":4,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Dr.\",\"people_count\":110,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}}],\"statuscode\":200}"
```

To filter that, I started to write a whitelister. He gets the hole json + the whitelist in the form array("statuscode","response.name","response.id","total").
Now he should walk through this JSON recursive and return a json with the same structure but with all the other nodes removed.

This is my current state:

```
public function filter($response,$whitelist,$depth = 0) {
    $filteredResponse = "";

    foreach (json_decode($response,true) as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($whitelist as $item) {
            $items = explode(".",$item);
            foreach($items as $it) {
                if($it === $key && strlen($it)>0) {
                    if(is_array($value)) {
                        for($i=1;$i<count($items);$i++) {
                            $str .= $it.".";
                        }
                        $filteredResponse[$it] = $this->filter(json_encode($value),array($str),$depth+1);
                    }
                    else $filteredResponse[$key] = $value;
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return json_encode($filteredResponse);
}
```

My result at the moment is *{"total":6,"response":"\"\"","statuscode":200}*.
Can anyone help my out?

Comment: Your JSON is a string that contains more JSON?

Comment: I'm getting a string like shown above. with json_decode() and json_encode I'm getting my json or giving back the string.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario no its regular json (Firefox parses it fine)

Comment: I would recommend writing a filter function that already takes a decoded array, and reencode the result into json - so that it is only concerned with a php-array not JSON

Comment: @birdspider - What's shown in the question does not pass [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), that's why I'm asking. Though it's probably not relevant to the question: I think it's all about how to loop deeply nested arrays, rather than JSON.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario probably because JSONLint parses JS-JSON not the string representation (escaped \" and such), if you do JSON.parse(str) in any browser it should be fine

Comment: We should really stop giving the name JSON to any intermediate variable, object, array or string that is originated from or aimed to become JSON at some point. *sigh*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is a working version, which solves my problem:

```
    public function filter($response,$whiteList,$depth = 0) {
    $filteredResponse = $response;

    foreach ($filteredResponse as $key => $value) {
        $isBlackListed = true;

        foreach ($whiteList as $whiteItem) {
            $whiteTokens = explode(".", $whiteItem);

            if($depth >= count($whiteTokens))
                continue;
            if($key !== $whiteTokens[$depth])
                continue;
            else {
                if(is_array($value)) {
                    $isBlackListed = false;

                    if(!$this->is_assoc($value)) {
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach($value as $element) {
                            $filteredResponse[$key][$i] = $this->filter($element, $whiteList, $depth+1);
                            $i++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        if(count($whiteTokens) != $depth+1)
                            $filteredResponse[$key] = $this->filter($value, $whiteList, $depth+1);
                    }
                } else {
                    $isBlackListed = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if($isBlackListed) 
            unset($filteredResponse[$key]);

        $isBlackListed = true;
    }
    return $filteredResponse;
}

private function is_assoc($array) {
    return (bool)count(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_string'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$str = "{\"total\":6,\"sort\":{\"field\":\"created_at\",\"order\":\"desc\"},\"constraints\":       [],\"pagination\":  {\"current\":1,\"previous\":null,\"next\":null,\"per_page\":25,\"pages\":1,\"count\":6},\"response\":[{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Prof. Dr. Dr. h. c.\",\"people_count\":2,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"Dr. h. c.\",\"people_count\":1,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Dr. Dr.\",\"people_count\":0,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":true}},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Prof. Dr.\",\"people_count\":0,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":true}},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"Prof.\",\"people_count\":4,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Dr.\",\"people_count\":110,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}}],\"statuscode\":200}";


$arr = json_decode($str, true);


$arr_new = array();
$arr_new['total'] = $arr['total'];
$arr_new['statuscode'] = $arr['statuscode'];

foreach($arr['response'] as $arr_response)
{
      $arr_temp = array();
      $arr_temp['id'] = $arr_response['id'];
      $arr_temp['name'] = $arr_response['name'];
      $arr_new['response'][] = $arr_temp; 
}

print_r($arr_new);

echo json_encode($arr_new);
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [total] => 6
    [statuscode] => 200
    [response] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [name] => Prof. Dr. Dr. h. c.
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [name] => Dr. h. c.
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [name] => Dr. Dr.
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [name] => Prof. Dr.
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => Prof.
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => Dr.
                )

        )

)

{"total":6,"statuscode":200,"response":[{"id":10,"name":"Prof. Dr. Dr. h. c."},{"id":9,"name":"Dr. h. c."},{"id":8,"name":"Dr. Dr."},{"id":7,"name":"Prof. Dr."},{"id":6,"name":"Prof."},{"id":5,"name":"Dr."}]}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/177376)

Comment: Thanks again. But I think my question was not clear enough. Your solution works fine - but it's hardcoded. I need a function call like filter($json,$whitelist,..) and $whitelist=["total","statuscode","response.name","response.id"]; But it should also work with ["sort","response.name","response.people_count"]; or a complete different JSON.

Comment: that's why I going through my list with foreach ($whitelist as $item) { $items = explode(".",$item); .... }

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$str = "{\"total\":6,\"sort\":{\"field\":\"created_at\",\"order\":\"desc\"},\"constraints\":       [],\"pagination\":  {\"current\":1,\"previous\":null,\"next\":null,\"per_page\":25,\"pages\":1,\"count\":6},\"response\":[{\"id\":10,\"name\":\"Prof. Dr. Dr. h. c.\",\"people_count\":2,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":9,\"name\":\"Dr. h. c.\",\"people_count\":1,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":8,\"name\":\"Dr. Dr.\",\"people_count\":0,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":true}},{\"id\":7,\"name\":\"Prof. Dr.\",\"people_count\":0,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":true}},{\"id\":6,\"name\":\"Prof.\",\"people_count\":4,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"Dr.\",\"people_count\":110,\"allowed_actions\":{\"destroy\":false}}],\"statuscode\":200}";


$arr = json_decode($str, true);


$arr_new = array();
$arr_new['total'] = $arr['total'];
$arr_new['statuscode'] = $arr['statuscode'];

foreach($arr['response'] as $arr_response)
{
      $arr_new['response_id'][] = $arr_response['id'];
      $arr_new['response_name'][] = $arr_response['name'];
}

print_r($arr_new);
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [total] => 6
    [statuscode] => 200
    [response_id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 8
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 5
        )

    [response_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Prof. Dr. Dr. h. c.
            [1] => Dr. h. c.
            [2] => Dr. Dr.
            [3] => Prof. Dr.
            [4] => Prof.
            [5] => Dr.
        )

)
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/177362)**

Comment: thanks for you fast help. but the problem is, that this filter should work in general for all JSON in this form with every whitelist input. so I've to walk through my input and work recursive. Thats my big problem... I don't get that to work :(

Comment: what you trying to get?

Comment: for example I've the old response from above: http://pastebin.com/4e4XRmCV and my whitefilter is array("statuscode","response.id","response.name") I want this output: http://pastebin.com/XZJkEMKF Hope my problem is more clear now?

Comment: i have add one more answer try that now

Comment: sadly this problem is more complicated... :(